# .NET MVC 5 Reset cookie upon page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, cookies

I have an odd issue where I try to set the cookie value in Razor view like this:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    HttpCookie e = new HttpCookie("d");
    e.Value = @Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();
    e.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(999); // expires after 30 days
    Response.Cookies.Add(e);
}
```

And then I form the URL based on this cookie value like this:

```
@foreach(//some collection)
{
  <a href="/Items/Index/@Request.Cookies["d"].Value"></a>
}
```

So let's say that first route id value was:

```
user123
```

And next route id value:

```
user1234
```

When the page loads first time links look like this:

```
/Items/Index/user123
```

When 2nd time I pass the route id value as user1234 link still remains the same like:

```
/Items/Index/user123
```

Only 3rd time when I refresh the page the URL then changes to:

```
/Items/Index/user1234
```

I would like to set the cookie value to a new value each time the page loads and then form the url based on that route id value which is stored in cookie...

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing odd here. Think about the flow:

The view loads the first time with id `user123`.The engine executes the response and creates the cookie with this value. The cookie will go with the **response** but it will only be available on the *next* **request**.

On the second **request** with id `user1234`, the cookie is now available, with the value from the last **response** (`user123`), so you get that in your link, although you are now setting it to the next value (`user1234`) in the **response**.

In other words, you are always one step behind because you are trying to set the cookie and read the cookie at the same time. For the cookie to be set, it has to be sent back to the browser first so it can be available on subsequent requests.

You could fix this by first checking to see if the cookie exists. If it doesn't, generate your link using the value that came in the route data and set the cookie, otherwise generate the link using the value in the cookie.

Comment: Should I then rather set it in action ? Or is there any workaround ?

Comment: @User987: I updated my answer to give you an idea of how to fix this.

Comment: Okay but what about when the cookie does exists and route id stays the same ?

Comment: Without knowing much about what you are doing, it looks to me like you are trying to identify the user by the route data and then saving the identity from there on, right? If that is the case, I would recommend moving the cookie setting code to a controller base or an attribute and leaving the generation of the link to the view.

Comment: Okay I solved it, I just use initially route value id, and then on other pages cookies value..